# In practice, why compare integer is better than compare string?

Tags: python, time, python-3.x, comparison

I did this test

```
import time
def test1():
    a=100
    b=200
    start=time.time()
    if (a>b):
        c=a
    else:
        c=b
    end=time.time()
    print(end-start)


def test2():
    a="amisetertzatzaz1111reaet"
    b="avieatzfzatzr333333ts"
    start=time.time()

    if (a>b):
        c=a
    else:
        c=b
    end=time.time()
    print(end-start)

 def test3():
     a="100"
     b="200"
     start=time.time()

     if (a>b):
         c=a
     else:
         c=b
     end=time.time()
     print(end-start)
```

And obtain as result

```
1.9073486328125e-06    #test1()
9.5367431640625e-07    #test2()
1.9073486328125e-06    #test3()
```

Execution times are similar. It's true, use integer instead of string reduce the storage space but what about the execution time?

Comment: What is it about the execution time you want to know?

Comment: @martineau: i would understand why it is usually said that it is better to use integers than strings; GarethRees gave me a good orientation

Answer (score 7):

Timing a single execution of a short piece of code doesn't tell you very much at all. In particular, if you look at the timing numbers from your `test1` and `test3`, you'll see that *the numbers are identical*. That ought to be a warning sign that, in fact, all that you're seeing here is the resolution of the timer:

```
>>> 2.0 / 2 ** 20
1.9073486328125e-06
>>> 1.0 / 2 ** 20
9.5367431640625e-07
```

For better results, you need to run the code many times, and measure and subtract the timing overhead. Python has a built-in module [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) for doing exactly this. Let's time 100 million executions of each kind of comparison:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('100 > 200', number=10**8)
5.98881983757019
>>> timeit('"100" > "200"', number=10**8)
7.528342008590698
```

so you can see that the difference is not really all that much (string comparison only about 25% slower in this case). So why is string comparison slower? Well, the way to find out is to look at the implementation of the comparison operation.

In Python 2.7, comparison is implemented by the [`do_cmp` function in `object.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2a3884b6ffb5/Objects/object.c#l811). (Please open this code in a new window to follow the rest of my analysis.) On line 817, you'll see that if the objects being compared are the same type and if they have a `tp_compare` function in their class structure, then that function is called. In the case of integer objects, this is what happens, the function being [`int_compare` in `intobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2a3884b6ffb5/Objects/intobject.c#l438), which you'll see is very simple.

But strings don't have a `tp_compare` function, so `do_cmp` proceeds to call [`try_rich_to_3way_compare`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2a3884b6ffb5/Objects/object.c#l668) which then calls [`try_rich_compare_bool`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2a3884b6ffb5/Objects/object.c#l641) up to three times (trying the three comparison operators EQ, LT and GT in turn). This calls [`try_rich_compare`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2a3884b6ffb5/Objects/object.c#l606) which calls [`string_richcompare` in `stringobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2a3884b6ffb5/Objects/stringobject.c#l1186).

So string comparison is slower because it has to use the complicated "rich comparison" infrastructure, whereas integer comparison is more direct. But even so, it doesn't make all that much difference.

Comment: In your example "100" and "200" can be compared only by looking to the first character. But try to compare, e.g. ("123456789" > "123456788") vs. (123456789 > 123456788).

Comment: @NikolayVyahhi: did you actually try timing those? Each additional character that needs to be compared adds less than 2% to the comparison time, so for short strings the most important factor is still the "rich comparison" overhead that I described in my answer.

Comment: @GarethRees: Thank you, your explanation is clear. I understand also that the difference is not really significative in term of execution time, string comparison is slower then integer comparison, but the difference is not too bad, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Huh? Since the storage space is reduced, the number of bits that need to be compared is also reduced. Comparing bits is work, doing less work means it goes faster.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to write a function that compares two bits faster than two bytes. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy No, for most modern general-purpose instruction sets I guess a byte is the smallest amount of information that can be processed. But the answer was not about that case, it was comparing integers vs comparing strings. In general "fewer bits = less work" is true, but typical practical computers quantize things so it's not a linear relationship.