# pandas Series: compare values all vs. all

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with two columns: `sequence` and `id` such as:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {"id":["seq1", "seq2", "seq3"], "sequence":["ATCTGC", "AACTGC", "AACTCC"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

(this is a small example of an actual dataset of +20k sequences)

And I am trying to get a **sequence-distance matrix** in an efficient way. Distance is understood as the number of different characters between each sequence.
To do so, I need to apply **a function of all vs. all values** in the `sequence` column.

My current code looks like this:

```py
def count_differences( seq, df ):
  return df.apply(lambda x: sum(1 for i, j in zip(x["sequence"], seq) if i != j), axis=1)

df2 = df.apply(lambda x: count_differences( x["sequence"], df), axis=1)
df2 = df2.rename(df["id"], axis="columns").rename(df["id"], axis="rows")

#      seq1 seq2 seq3
# seq1    0    1    2
# seq2    1    0    1
# seq3    2    1    0
```

which is an apply inside an apply. It works fine, but when running it over all the sequences I have it does take quite a bit.

Is there a more efficient way to go about it? I've been trying to see if there is something that can be done with `Series.map` to speed this up, but I haven't found any solution so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one idea, which involves dropping down to `numpy`.

There are several steps, but since the underlying work is done via `numpy` numeric arrays, this may be more efficient.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

data = {"id":["seq1", "seq2", "seq3"], "sequence":["ATCTGC", "AACTGC", "AACTCC"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

a = np.array(list(map(list, df['sequence'])))
values = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(a.shape)

n = len(a)
d = {(i, j): np.sum(a[i]!=a[j]) for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if j > i}

res = np.zeros((n, n))
keys = list(zip(*d.keys()))

res[keys[0], keys[1]] = list(d.values())
res += res.T

df_res = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=data['id'], index=data['id'], dtype=int)

#       seq1  seq2  seq3
# seq1     0     1     2
# seq2     1     0     1
# seq3     2     1     0
```

**Explanation**

- Convert your sequence to a `numpy` array, which each element is a letter.
- Factorize your array (i.e. associate each letter with a number) using `np.unique`.
- Use `np.sum` to find letter-wise differences between rows in your factorized array, and add results to a dictionary. Since your result is triangular, only perform half the calculations.
- Create new `numpy` array from the dictionary and add inverse to make triangular array full.
- Convert your dictionary to a dataframe.

**Performance benchmarking**

I see a ~7x performance improvement.

```
%timeit original(df)  # 3.32s
%timeit jp(df)        # 461ms

import pandas as pd, numpy as np

data = {"id":["seq1", "seq2", "seq3"], "sequence":["ATCTGC", "AACTGC", "AACTCC"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = pd.concat([df]*100)

def original(df):
    def count_differences( seq, df ):
        return df.apply(lambda x: sum(1 for i, j in zip(x["sequence"], seq) if i != j), axis=1)

    df2 = df.apply(lambda x: count_differences( x["sequence"], df), axis=1)

    return df2

def jp(df):

    a = np.array(list(map(list, df['sequence'])))
    values = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(a.shape)

    n = len(a)
    d = {(i, j): np.sum(a[i]!=a[j]) for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if j > i}

    res = np.zeros((n, n))
    keys = list(zip(*d.keys()))

    res[keys[0], keys[1]] = list(d.values())
    res += res.T

    df_res = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=range(len(df['id'])), index=range(len(df['id'])), dtype=int)

    return df_res
```

Comment: I was trying it too with my bigger set and also get a nice improvement, and checking that the output `DataFrames` were identical. It is a very nice solution. I gotta say, though, `values` is assigned but never used. I've comment it on my code and it just works the same. I guess string comparison just works as fine? I liked how you limit to half the calculations.

Comment: I expect string comparison to be more expensive versus comparing numbers (maybe more memory allocation / larger overhead / but not sure).

Comment: This is an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14401258/9209546) comparing string vs integer comparison, not sure if it is still relevant though. The algorithm appears to be entirely different.

Comment: I see. I guess the question here is if this is would be considered string comparison or char comparison (as we are already picking positions), which I guess might be... ¿faster? In any case, your solution works like a charm.